# Can't start default file manager on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lxde, mate, x2go

I run an Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and access it remotely with X2Go. Currently I have tried both `Mate` and `LXDE` but neither works correctly. I can log in and browse the desktop menu, but no desktop icons which is the sign of file manager fails to start. I open konsole/terminal and start the file manager from there. It is very strange that I can start the file manager that is not the default of one desktop environment. That is, I can start `nautilus`, `caja` when I am in LXDE; and I can start `pcmanfm` when I am in Mate session. If I run `caja` from `Mate Termimal`, nothing is showing up.

Looking at /var/log/syslog, I could see several red lines like this:

```
/usr/bin/x2gomountdirs[35964]: WARNING: mounting of /home/x2goclient/.x2go/S-x2goserver-50-1417265685_stDGNOME_dp24/spool failed
mate-session WARNING: Client '/org/mate/SessionManager/Client4' failed to reply before timeout
```

Comment: When putting in blocks of text, put 4 spaces `    ` before it to format it as code, rather than the `\`\`\`` 3 backticks

Comment: Thanks, I keep being confused between stackoverflow and github.

Comment: see here https://l3net.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/adding-home-trash-and-web-icons-to-linux-desktop/

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using nautilus, Then try re-installing Nautilus file manager again !

First,try updating the Repositories. Use this code (In a terminal):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and press enter. Then,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

(In a terminal) and press enter

Hope this works !

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not using `nautilus`. My problem really is how to get the default file manager up and running, i.e. `caja` for `MATE`, `pcmanfm` for `LXDE`. `Nautilus` is just the default file manager for `GNOME` which I don't use.

Comment: @biocyberman 
Then which one you are using as default ?

Comment: I use `caja` for `MATE` desktop environment, and `pcmanfm` for `LXDE` desktop environment. Maybe you don't use neither of them?

Comment: I've used pcmanfm before in my Ubuntu @biocyberman !!!
But I don't really understood what did you mean by this question !
What do you really want ?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @NivedKannada. I want to solve to problem I described in the question. Meaning that if I login with either `MATE` or `LXDE` I should be able to use the remote desktop normally; the corresponding file manager should be ready for me to use.